# prepareForSegue nil swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to use ｀prepareForSegue｀ but it doesnt get called for some reason.  I named the segue correctly and ive used almost the same code in other parts of my app but for some reason the app keeps crashing saying found nil when i go to the next view.

TableViewController:

```
class ChartsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var song: NSURL!
    var player:AVPlayer!

    @IBOutlet var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var songs = [PFObject]()
    var parseImage: PFFile!

    @IBOutlet var hideDislikeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var hideLikeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var segment: UISegmentedControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var stopButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("stopMusic"))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = stopButton

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt") //new songs
        query.limit = 100
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                //self.songs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                for object in objects {
                    self.songs.append(object as PFObject)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        Flurry.logEvent("Charts View")


    }

    func stopMusic() {
        if (isPlaying == true) {
            if (player.rate > 0) && (player.error == nil) {
                //playing
                player.pause()
            }
            isPlaying = false
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
        var obj : PFObject? = nil
        if(indexPath.row < self.songs.count){
            obj = self.songs[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        }


        return obj
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songs.count

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "commentSegue" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

                let object: PFObject = songs[indexPath.row]
                println(indexPath.row)
                println(songs)
                println(object)
                (segue.destinationViewController as CommentsViewController).detailItem = object

            }
        }
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8
        let objectSong: PFObject = songs[indexPath.row]
        println(objectSong)
        parseImage = objectSong.valueForKey("picture") as PFFile
        let imgURL = NSURL(string: parseImage.url)
        cell.songImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.songImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.songImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.songImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.songImage.frame.height/4
        cell.songImage.clipsToBounds = true



        cell.songImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: parseImage.url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "MeipLogo"))

        cell.songTitleLabel.text = objectSong.valueForKey("title") as? String
        cell.artistNameLabel.text = objectSong.valueForKey("artistName") as? String

        let user = PFUser.currentUser()

        return cell

    }
```

NextViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var commentsView: UITableView!
    var commentsArray = [String]()
    @IBOutlet var songImage: UIImageView!
    var songObject: PFObject!

    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        songObject = configureView()
        songImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        songImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        songImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        songImage.layer.cornerRadius = songImage.frame.height/4
        songImage.clipsToBounds = true
        println(songObject)
        let parseImage: PFFile =  songObject.valueForKey("picture") as PFFile

        songImage.image = UIImage(data: parseImage.getData())
        if songObject["comments"] != nil {

            commentsArray = songObject["comments"] as [String]
        }

        commentsView.delegate = self
        commentsView.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return commentsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("textCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if (commentsArray.count == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = "No Comments! Be The First One smile emoticon"
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: How are you trying to trigger the segue? How do you create the instance of TableViewController that has this prepareForSegue method?

Comment: the only thing it tells me in the error log is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I trigger the segue in my storyboard when user clicks button it goes to the next view. My next view is a uiviewcontroller with a uitableview could that be the issue?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see if it pinpoints the offending line.

Comment: Post your relevant code that `songs` in the `TableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `detailItem` is not being set when you expect, so the crash occurs when you unwrap it in `configureView` but the value is nil.  This design is kind of weird, as well.  I would do something like this instead:

```
var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() -> PFObject? {
    if let song = self.detailItem as? PFObject {
        // Do something with the `song` here
        return song
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` the `detailItem` has not been set yet, therefore it will crash. Why? Probably because the assigment in `prepareForSegue` is wrong, log the object and the indexPath.

In addition you might want to move the assigment of `songObject` into `configureView` as well as any eventual future actions depedant of said object. Either call `configureView` from `viewDidLoad` OR from `didSet` - both together is one too often...

Comment: thanks for youe help but the app still crashes. i used the exact same code on another part of my app and it works fine but for some reason here it doesnt.

Comment: Where does it crash now and with what message?

Comment: Does let object: AnyObject = songs actually work / is songs a valid PFObject? What does the log print?

Comment: you are right whe i println(object) i get nil but i am using songs[indexPath.row] for cellForRowAtIndex and i get the pfobject

Comment: Okay, is the indexPath correct, try to log him aus well

Comment: It's not true. Prepare for segue is always called before viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ehhhm, you are right, derping around, too early in the day

Comment: doesnt print for some reason

Comment: What does not log? The indexPath? Try to set a breakpoint and inspect what it is, what songs and what obejct is.

Comment: i log it before println(object) but no value and i updated question to contain all code i am using

Comment: Have you tried debugging it via setting a breakpoint and inspecting all the values?